# How to reliably avoid iphone idle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I don't want my app to go to sleep (shut screen off) unless the user puts it out of its misery.  I'm trying what I think is simple code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {  
    application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

This works most of the time, but the app still occasionally goes to sleep.  I'm not sure of the pattern.  Is there anything that can reenable the idle timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some classes (such as `MPMoviePlayerController`) will enable/disable the idleTimer as part of their normal workings.

Comment: ahh.  Is there a list somewhere, so I can reset the idletimer after using the offending class?

Comment: There is no list that I know of, but as a last resort you can always reset it on an NSTimer

Answer (score 0):

rpetrich is right.

I was launching a MoviePlayerController out of my app and on the callback I was forced to set idleTimerDisabled to YES again... But there's a remark here because for some reason iphone is discarding this set...

I solved it, this way:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {  
    application.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
}
```